# WPF - ListBox show longdate instead of shortdate by objects inside?

Tags: wpf

I am adding date objects in a ListBox. However, the shortdate are shown but i want to show the longdate is there a simple way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ItemStringFormat` property to "D" (long date pattern)